# cshtml template + model passing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I've just joined half-finished project and I'm faily new to asp.net mvc.
I've noticed that the project has fair amount of controllers and also they're accompanied by even greater amount of views.
So the problem is many of these controllers extract data from the db and call a _*controllername*TableResult.cshtml view to render it (it's a partial view). 
Now these views are very VERY similar and I find this code repeating somehow annoying (for creating new views). The problem I've found so far is that you have to pass the model

```
@model List<GroceriesTableModel>
```

There're some other differences like - ajax(actionName, controllerName) and id`s of the html - but all these can be fixed with a Dictionary?

**My question**: is there a way to somehow template these look alike views - and pass the correct model and a Dictionary object for the id`s?

Comment: Could you be more clear, I can't get what you realy need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure is - `@Html.RenderPartial("_partialview", model, Dictionary)`

search renderpartial for more details...